# How to scale values according to a counter

Tags: c++, c++11

I have five integer values

```
std::vector<int> vec(5, 0);
```

the value of each int will be based on a counter.

if counter is 0 than all the ints would be 0

if the counter is 100 than all the ints will have value of 20

so when the counter is 20 the first int will have a value of 20 and the rest will be 0.

when the counter is 30 the first int will be 20 and the second int will be 10

This is my code for this i am interested to see other logics to attain this,

```
std::vector<int> vec(5, 0);
    int counter = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int startValue = (i) * 20;
        int finalValue = counter - startValue;

        if (finalValue > 20)
            finalValue = 20;

        if (finalValue < 0)
            finalValue = 0;

        vec[i] = finalValue;
    }


    for (auto &v : vec)
    {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but if you're looking for something "clever", try this::

```
int counter = 30;
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    if( counter <= 20 * i ) {
        vec[i] = 0;
    } else {
        vec[i] = (counter > 20 * (1 + i)) ? 20 : counter % 20;      // how I think, or
        vec[i] = (counter - (20 * i) > 20) ? 20 : counter - 20 * i; // how you do it
    }
}
```

You could probably micro-optimize the loop to replace the second multiplication with an addition, but you're unlikely to optimize better than the compiler does with its loop unrolling option.

I'm not an avid user of StackOverflow (yet) but this question seems like it would be better posted at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), based on [this answer on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 1):

```
while(counter>0&&i<5)
{
    if(counter>=20)
    {
        vec[i]+=20;
        counter-=20;
    }
    else
    {
        vec[i]+=counter%20;
        counter=counter-counter%20;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Basically it cuts down the counter by 20 or %20 each time and sets it into the array. It is also useful for working with numbers that are too large.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to precalculate how many elements are to be set to `20` and what's left for the next element, then leave the others at `0`.

```
    const int maxValue = 20;
    int fullCells = counter / maxValue;
    int lastValue = counter % maxValue; 

    for (int i = 0; i < fullCells; i++)
    {   vec[i] = maxValue; }
    if (lastValue)
    {   vec[fullCells] = lastValue; }
```